# change volume of mp3 playing via wmplib in c#

Tags: c#, volume, wmplib

Is it somehow possible to change the volume of a mp3-file that is playing via wmplib? Changing the volume of the program itself would be ok as well.

Are there any solutions to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to send [WM_APPCOMMAND message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9203952/490018)).

For WPF use [WindowInteropHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.aspx) to get the `Handle` of the `Window`:

```
class MainWindow : Window
{
    ...

    private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
    private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;
    private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 10 * 65536;
    private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 9 * 65536;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private void VolumeUp()
    {
        // APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP or APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN
        var windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
        SendMessageW(windowInteropHelper.Handle, (IntPtr)WM_APPCOMMAND, windowInteropHelper.Handle, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
    }
}
```

For Windows Forms use [Control.Handle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx):

```
class MainForm : Form
{
    ...

    private void VolumeUp()
    {
        SendMessageW(Handle, (IntPtr)WM_APPCOMMAND, Handle, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for the answer. I already saw that topic/answer but the code only gives me a bunch of errors. I´m using WindowsForms and i´m not sure if it´s because the WindowInteropHelper (or the namespace) might be limited to WPF.

Comment: I´m still getting a few errors on the SendMessageW-line, especially at  (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);. The errors are for example: "'System.IntPtr' is a 'Type' but is used like a 'variable'", "Invalid expression term ')'", "')' expected", "';' expected" and "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"...

Comment: @f4bzen, sorry! Corrected.

Comment: Ok, the code is now working for me, but I had to change the SendMessageW-line a little bit, since there was 1 argument missing in your version: SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);  So feel free to add this to your solution and thank you for helping me with this.

Answer (score 7):

This is a simple way to do it.

Example:

```
WMPlib.WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WMPlib.WindowsMediaPlayer(); //Creates an instance of the WMP
wmp.url="URI to media source"; //Sets media source
wmp.settings.volume= 50;  //Volume can be 0-100 (inclusive)
```

Hope it helped you!

Comment: Please can you tell me from which book or site tutorial you read this I also want to read the class library.

Comment: This is simpler and better than the accepted answer which changes the volume not only on the application but to the whole system so other apps are also affected. +1
To set volume up you can do something like `wmp.settings.volume += 1;`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wmsound= new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

wmsound.URL = @"C:\Users\USER\sound.mp3";

//Volume 100%
finish_sound.settings.volume = 100;
```