# How to change the volume by using mouse wheel?

Tags: c#, volume, mousewheel, wmp

I am new and know little about this. I am using `WMPLib` namespace.

I tried figuring out how to change the volume by using the mouse wheel:

```
void Form1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    wmpPlayer.settings.volume = //inc or dec
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What don't you know how to do?

Comment: Set the volume to a larger value than it currently is in that case.

Comment: `wmpPlayer.settings.volume += e.Delta;` where delta is positive when you scroll up or its negative when you scroll down. it should be something like this i guess you are using win form.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary no, it turns to 0 or 100 when i scroll up or down - i finally got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers...

I finally got it:

```
    void Form1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Delta > 0)
            wmpPlayer.settings.volume = activeMusic.settings.volume + 1;
        else
            wmpPlayer.settings.volume = activeMusic.settings.volume - 1;

        //to check the volume no.
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(wmpPlayer.settings.volume));
    }
```

Comment: good one but how `wmpPlayer.settings.volume += e.Delta;` does not work? just curious ,

Comment: test it :) i tested it and check it with `MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(wmpPlayer.settings.volume))`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simple use a wmpPlayer.settings.volume++ to achieve this ? 
You would just have to find a way to check if it's a scrolldown or scrollup !

---

Check out this post, it might be helping : [Using WMP control, volume changes main app volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248115/using-wmp-control-volume-changes-main-app-volume)

Answer (score 0):

A property can have a get or set method to it !

```
wmpPlayer.settings.volume= wmpPlayer.settings.volume + myValue;
```

So you first get the current volume value and add to it your value which could be positive or negative depending upon scroll up/down and finally you set it as the final volume

Comment: @cromix That would depend upon wheel rotation by user :  Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel(v=vs.110).aspx) !       Panel_MouseWheel();//Modify this in the code